# AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type' Tensorflow Serving

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to use a function (from another module) inside tensorflow. The function accepts a numpy array and returns the changepoints. My main goal is to deploy this model on tensorflow serving. I am running into error

> AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type'

There are 2 functions, one is create_data() that creates a numpy array and returns it, another is change() which accepts numpy array and uses the before mentioned function to return changepoints. I have created a placeholder to accept input data, an operation to execute the function. Problem is, if i try to send data through placeholder, i run into error. If i send the data directly into the function, it runs. Following is my code.

```
def create_data():
    np.random.seed(0)
    size = 100
    mean_a = 0.0
    mean_b = 10.0
    mean_c = 0
    var = 0.1
    data_a = np.random.normal(mean_a, var, size)
    data_b = np.random.normal(mean_b, var, size)
    data_c = np.random.normal(mean_c, var, size)
    data = np.concatenate([data_a, data_b, data_c])
    return data

def change(data):
    # what else i tried
    # data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
    # above line gives another error mentioned after code 
    cpts = (pelt(normal_mean(x, np.var(x)), len(x)))
    return cpts

sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[300, ], name="myInput")
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(change(x),np.float32,name="myOutput")
z = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:create_data()})
```

If i try the code `data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)` in the function change(), it gives me error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I also tried `data = np.hstack((data)).astype(np.float)` and `data = np.vstack((data)).astype(np.float)` but it runs into a separate error that says use tf.map_fn. I also tried to use tf.eval() to convert the numbers but i couldn't get them to run inside a function with placeholders.

But if i send in the output directly,

```
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(change(create_data()),np.float32,name="myOutput")
```

It works.

How should i send in the input to make it work?

EDIT: The function in question is [this](https://github.com/ruipgil/changepy) if anyone wants to know.

Answer (score 3):

This error is raised when you try to pass a Tensor into a numpy function

You need to use [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to include python function into tensorflow graph

(also, your change() functin uses data as argument instead of x)

Here is the code that worked for me

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from changepy import pelt
from changepy.costs import normal_mean

def create_data():
    np.random.seed(0)
    size = 100
    mean_a = 0.0
    mean_b = 10.0
    mean_c = 0
    var = 0.1
    data_a = np.random.normal(mean_a, var, size)
    data_b = np.random.normal(mean_b, var, size)
    data_c = np.random.normal(mean_c, var, size)
    data = np.concatenate([data_a, data_b, data_c])
    return data

def change(x):
    # what else i tried
    # data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
    # above line gives another error mentioned after code 

    cpts = (pelt(normal_mean(x, np.var(x)), len(x)))
    return cpts


sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[300, ], name="myInput")
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.compat.v1.py_func(change, [x], 3*[tf.int64]),np.float32,name="myOutput")
z = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x:create_data()})
print(z)
```